# OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to storage.googleapis.com:443

Tags: 18.04, curl, openssl, kubernetes

I've been trying to install minikube on my Ubuntu machine as per this [post](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/).

But whenever I try to run...

```
curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64 \
  && chmod +x minikube
```

... I got following error.

> OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to storage.googleapis.com:443

For more details please check attached screenshot.
[image]

OS Version:**Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS**

Curl Version:  **curl 7.58.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)**

OpenSSL Version: **OpenSSL/1.1.1**

*So far I've tried to run this command by downgrading curl to 7.33, upgrading to 7.68 and even reinstalled my OS and tried this command but its always shows me same error. I've been scratching my head to solve this problem for last 2 night any suggestion or solution would be much appreciated.*

Comment: Hi, i am having the same problem, with google.com the problem seems to be intermittent, with github.com the problem is more reproducible. the problem is also not related to any OS. 
It does work with "Redhat7.6: curl 7.29.0" and "SLES12 SP3: curl 7.37.0" 
but it does not work with openSUSE Tumbleweed: curl 7.50.3" nor "SLES11 SP3: curl 7.19.7" nor "Alpine Linux v3.10: curl 7.67.0"
i have not been able to find the cause yet, and not many people seem to experience it, i will keep you posted of my progress, please share yours as well

Answer (score 0):

### It was my router issue

Please check your router to see if it is doing a transparent proxy for you?

If it is, then you may want to turn that off.

If you can't turn it off, then you might want to install a VPN solution that will allow you to bypass it.

Just a thought.

Just got this solution from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1264498/homebrew-gives-ssl-error-ssl-error-syscall-on-home-network)